# c - Bus error when trying to use memcpy() on pointer made from mmap()

Tags: c

I get a "bus error" when trying to run some cross-compiled code on ARM and I've traced it to to this:

```
    int * arr;
    arr = (int *)malloc(BUF*sizeof(int));       

    memcpy(arr,&cha_signal[trig_ptr],BUF*sizeof(int));
```

trig_ptr is an integer pointing to where my signal begins; BUF the size of the buffer (~16000).

The thing that doesn't make sense is if I loop through cha_signal manually, using

```
for(i=0; i < BUF; i++) { //do stuff }
```

I can access all of its elements fine! For some reason, the seemingly equivalent memcpy() operation chokes.  I suspect, but am not knowledgable enough to confirm, that this is due to how cha_signal was made:

```
/* Map FPGA memory space to page_ptr. */
page_ptr = mmap(NULL, OSC_FPGA_BASE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_SHARED, g_osc_fpga_mem_fd, page_addr);
if((void *)page_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
   //cleanup code
}

/* Set FPGA OSC module pointers to correct values. */
g_osc_fpga_reg_mem = page_ptr + page_off;
g_osc_fpga_cha_mem = (uint32_t *)g_osc_fpga_reg_mem + 
    (OSC_FPGA_CHA_OFFSET / sizeof(uint32_t));

...

*cha_signal = (int *)g_osc_fpga_cha_mem;
```

Any ideas? I noticed one other guy who had a similar problem, but there he was trying to write to space that wasn;t allocated. I believe I am allocating correctly here.

Comment: I would print out the values of `&cha_signal[trig_ptr]` and `BUF*sizeof(int))`.  Verify that the former is 4-byte aligned, and that the sum of the two doesn't run past the end of the FPGA memory region.

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed a bit more code.. apparently `cha_signal` has type `int **` or `void **` (otherwise the last line you posted won't work) , so `cha_signal[trig_ptr]` would be an `int *` or `void *`, but then you copy that pointer into an array of `int`.

Comment: @user2022444 Did you ever figure this problem out? I'm very curious to know if my answer actually described the problem you were encountering.

Answer (score 4):

**I suspect that your implementation of `memcpy` is simply incompatible with the way your hardware wants to be read.**

This is probably a question for the "hardware guys" that implemented whatever FPGA peripheral is on the other side of that `mmap`.

Since you seem to be accessing *hardware registers*, and not just plain old memory, you have to play by different rules. Some pieces of hardware *require* that you access memory by byte, or word, or other rules involving alignment.

The other part of the problem is that you don't know how `memcpy` is actually implemented. Often times it is a contrived, highly-optimized version, which tries to move data in the largest units possible, given alignment constraints. It could be this optimized version that is causing your problems. This theory is confirmed by the fact that you can use a standard `for` loop to iterate through.

Your best bet would be to run your application under a debugger, step through the `memcpy`, to see where the actual read from memory is causing the "bus error".